# Listing out the dependancies from a file based on what's required in the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

If I have a file called `index.js` and it requires a couple of modules. Is there any way I can get a list of the modules that are required?

```
var _ = require("underscore")
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
return app
```

Then I have another file like this.

```
var listRequired = require("list-required")
listRequired("./index.js").then(function(moduleTypes){
  console.log(moduleTypes.npm) // ["underscore", "express"]
})
```

I'd really also like a way to track npm modules (ex. `underscore`), native node modules (ex. `crypto`, `path`) and local files (ex. `./routes.js`)

So if `index.js` contained this:

```
var _ = require("underscore")
var express = require("express")
var routes = require("./routes")
var app = express()
module.exports = app
```

And `routes.js` contained this:

```
var crypto = require("crypto")
var Promise = require("bluebird")
module.exports = {}
```

Then I have another file like this.

```
var listRequired = require("list-required")/*(file, deepOption)*/
listRequired("./index.js", true).then(function(moduleTypes){
  console.log(moduleTypes.native) // ["crypto"]
  console.log(moduleTypes.local) // ["./routes"]
  console.log(moduleTypes.npm) // ["underscore", "express"]
})
```

Does this already exist in some capacity? ES6 `import` support would be nice as well.

Comment: Static analysis.  Use something that parses JavaScript source text and [walk the AST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059071/201952) looking for `require` calls.

Comment: Hey @josh3736 is there a specific static analysis tool that you'd recommend?

Comment: Looks like someone has already done it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/required

Comment: @josh3736 I'd be glad to accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique used to solve this kind of problem is called [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis).  You use something that parses source code and returns an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).  (This is very much like how a browser reads HTML and turns it into a DOM.)

Once you have an AST, it is relatively straightforward to walk the tree and look for interesting bits like `require` calls.

It looks like someone has already written a module that does exactly that, called [required](https://www.npmjs.com/package/required).