# What is a module and difference between module.exports vs exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been reading about this topic for several hours and just haven't found anything to help make this stick.

a module is just an object in node with a few properties, one is an exports property that references an object.

the 'exports' variable is

```
var exports = module.exports
```

It is a var pointing to the object that module.exports is referencing.

What I am struggling with is visualize what the module is.  I know it's an object, but is there only one?

I know this isn't the exact way node implements a module but I am visualizing it looking something like this:

```
var module = {}

module.exports = {}

// now module has a property module.exports

var exports = module.exports
```

Now, from everything I have been reading, if you were to assign something to module.export = 'xyz'

It would hold the value 'xyz'.  Does it lose the original object? On top of that, if I assigned something else to module.exports in the same file, would it be replaced with the new value?

```
EX: 

// file = app.js

module.export = 'hello'
module.export = 'bye'

// file = newApp.js

require(./app);
```

what is the value of the module? Am I overriding the same module object or are there multiple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before we continue, it's important that you understand [how modules are actually loaded by node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445642/201952).

The key thing to take away from node's module loading system is that before it actually runs the code you `require` (which happens in [`Module#_compile`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.16/lib/module.js#L374-457)), it [creates](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.16/lib/module.js#L39) a new, empty `exports` object as a property of the `Module`.  (In other words, your visualization is correct.)

Node then [wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20897174/201952) the text in the `require`d file with an anonymous function:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
// here goes what's in your js file
});
```

...and essentially `eval`s that string.  The result of `eval`ing that string is a function (the anonymous wrapper one), and node immediately *invokes* the function, passing in the parameters like this:

```
evaledFn(module.exports, require, module, filename, dirname);
```

`require`, `filename`, and `dirname` are a reference to the `require` function (which actually [isn't a global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20896892/201952)), and strings containing the loaded module's path information.  (This is what the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename) mean when they say "*`__filename` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.*")

So we can see that inside a module, indeed `exports === module.exports`.  But why do modules get both a `module` and a `exports`?

Backward compatibility.  In the very early days of node, there was no `module` variable inside of modules.  You simply assigned to `exports`.  However, this meant you could never export a constructor function as the module itself.

A familiar example of a module exporting a constructor function as the module:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

This works because [Express exports a function by reassigning `module.exports`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.4.8/lib/express.js#L14-18), overwriting the empty object that node gives you by default:

```
module.exports = function() { ... }
```

However, note that you can't just write:

```
exports = function { ... }
```

This is because [JavaScript's parameter passing semantics are weird](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/201952).  Technically, JavaScript might be considered "pure pass-by-value," but in reality parameters are passed "reference-by-value".

This means that you when you pass an object to a function, it receives a reference to that object as a value.  You can access the original object through that reference, but you cannot change the *caller's* perception of the reference.  In other words, there's no such thing as an "out" param like you might see in C/C++/C#.

As a concrete example:

```
var obj = { x: 1 };

function A(o) {
    o.x = 2;
}
function B(o) {
    o = { x: 2 };
}
```

Calling `A(obj);` will result in `obj.x == 2`, because we access the original object passed in as `o`.  However, `B(obj);` will do nothing; `obj.x == 1`.  Assigning a completely new object to `B`'s local `o` only changes what `o` points to.  It does nothing to the caller's object `obj`, which remains unaffected.

Now it should be obvious why it was thus necessary to add the `module` object to node modules' local scope.  In order to allow a module to completely replace the `exports` object, it must be available as the property an object passed in to the module anonymous function.  And obviously no one wanted to break existing code, so `exports` was left as a reference to `module.exports`.

So when you're just assigning properties to your exports object, it doesn't matter whether you use `exports` or `module.exports`; they are one and the same, a reference pointing to the exact same object.

It's only when you want to export a function as the top-level export where you *must* use `module.exports`, because as we've seen, simply assigning a function to `exports` would have no effect outside of the module scope.

As a final note, when you are exporting a function as the module, it's a good practice to assign to *both* `exports` and `module.exports`.  That way, both variables remain consistent and work the same as they do in a standard module.

```
exports = module.exports = function() { ... }
```

Be sure to do this near the top of your module file, so that no one accidentally assigns to an `exports` that ends up getting overwritten.

Also, if that looks strange to you (*three* `=`s?), I'm taking advantage of the fact that an expression containing the [assignment operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) returns the assigned value, which makes it possible to assign a single value to multiple variables in one shot.

Comment: Is the only reason why `express` assigns both variables at the same time really just "good practice" or "just in case"? Are there really no other reasons, or even fringe cases where it's better or even required?

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding the module — exports is a single object gets pulled in with `require`. Typically, when doing this kind of modular JavaScript using `require`, your export will be a constructor rather than a primitive like a string in your example. That way, you can create new instances of functionality that's defined in the module. Example:

```
// module.js
var MyConstructor = function(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
});

module.exports = MyConstructor;

// app.js
var MyConstructor = require('module');
var instance = new MyConstructor('test');
console.log(instance.prop) // 'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

Modules in Node.js are just files. Each file is a module and each module is a file. If you have more than one file, you can have more than one module (one in each file).

As per `module.exports`: [the Node.js API documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) will shed some light on the topic:

> The `module.exports` object is created by the Module system. Sometimes
>   this is not acceptable; many want their module to be an instance of
>   some class. To do this assign the desired export object to
>   `module.exports`. Note that assigning the desired object to `exports` will
>   simply rebind the local `exports` variable, which is probably not what
>   you want to do.

and

> The `exports` variable that is available within a module starts as a
>   reference to `module.exports`. As with any variable, if you assign a new
>   value to it, it is no longer bound to the previous value. ... As a guideline,
>   if the relationship between exports and module.exports
>   seems like magic to you, ignore exports and only use module.exports.

So, what does this all mean? In your particular example, `module.exports` would be equal to it's last assigned value (`'bye'`).